# Unexpected could not be prepared error on execute

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code that has an intentional syntax error for purposes of testing.

```
const string sql = @"
    INSERT RUNHISTORY ( r_activity_id)
                      (@r_activity_id)  -- Intentional missing VALUES
    ";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@r_activity_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0));
command.Prepare();
command.Parameters[0].Value = r_activity_id;

int rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();  // This line throws exception.
```

I am getting:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@r_activity_id'. 
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

I would expect to get that error on the `Prepare()` line rather than the `Execute()` line.

This is important to me because I prepare all the sql early in the excution of the program to catch problems and stop before the program does anything meaningful.

How can I catch this error on the `Prepare()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the method no longer throws an exception:

> Prior to Visual Studio 2010, Prepare threw an exception. Beginning in
>   Visual Studio 2010, this method does not throw an exception.[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx)